# Use a batch file to run powershell in admin mode

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before, but I've never quite found the answer to my question. I'm trying to run a PowerShell script through a batch file because I need to be able to launch the PowerShell in Administrator mode, but I need to be able to do so without have the pop up box to confirm or entering credentials. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: If you are asking if you can bypass the UAC prompt, then the answer is "no." This is by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO. Unless you change system security. See the network manager.

Optional security is not part of windows. Because it's not security if optional.

Your question is the same as *I'm writing a virus to infect computers and I want to bypass the security. What functions does windows have for bypassing security to allow infections*.

Comment: The op makes no mention if he will supply credentials. Could have been worth asking first. If nothing else this has to be a dup.

Comment: It explains the issue, they have probably been looking at it from a perspective that says _why is this in my way_.

Comment: Given that I answered a dupe of this, I know it's *possible* (with a bit of imagination), so this might reasonably have done better as a comment.

Comment: The network manager can probably help with security settings or turning UAC off. Vista has 10 different settings and Win 7 more. Anything is possible if elevated.

Comment: @NathanTuggy How does this stop any user from running any command using the $cred parameter.

Comment: @Serenity: $cred must be a PSCredentials object, which can only be obtained ultimately by authenticating through Windows. If you have a PSCredentials object that says you are user XYZ\Administrator, guess what, *you are user XYZ\Administrator*, same as if you have a command prompt running elevated that XYZ\Administrator started for you. The security boundary is elsewhere.

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for the responses. I was asking because I was originally trying to use a PowerShell script that I wrote using Secure String so we wouldn't have to hardcode a password into a batch file. However, we use KACE to run the program on other computers and it won't work for the script without elevated permission, but since we are running it remotely on computers over various locations I don't have the ability to log in as an admin or select yes from the prompt box. Thank you all again for the information.